# How do you read from a file when you do not know where the file will be located?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

Basically, I'm trying to set up a scanner that reads from a file. I know what the file name will be, but I won't know where it will be located. For testing purpose, I might know but if my teacher tests it, I won't know where the file would be located on their device.

Weirdly, I can't even seem to get it work with knowing the directory. 
From what I've searched up, people say that when you just search a file using: "testdata.txt", it should search the current directory your project is in. I've tried this by putting my test file into the folder where my project is located but I still get a FileNotFoundException.

```java
// Make scanner and read jobs into array
String fileName = "testdata.txt";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
```

Comment: I would pass the `fileName` as a command line argument. `String fileName = args[0];` and then run it like `java MyProject testdata.txt`

Comment: and what if there are 2 files with the same name? How would you know which is the right one?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Um...do you mean like read in user input? Not exactly sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @TehMattGR The filenames are specifically specified for this project. So there will be definitely 3 files, no more, no less. There names are "testdata1.txt", "testdata2.txt", and "testdata3.txt". We are expected to hardcode it into our program, read in from it, and then simulate some algorithm with the data.

Comment: ok then. What Im thinking of is that you should check one by one all the system's file names but this is gonna take sooooo long. The most softwares save their files to Program Files (x86) so its easier to find them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the use of `FileInputStream`s and `BufferedReader`s. In my experience, the `Scanner` class is a bit strange. You could try something like this if you're only reading from the file:

```
File file = new File("path.txt");

List<String> jobs = new ArrayList<String>();

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)) {
    String line = "";

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        jobs.add(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle errors
}

String[] jobArr = new String[jobs.size()];
jobs.toArray(jobArr);
```

This way you can also read on a line-to-line basis and handle each line separately.

Comment: I'm not familiar with buffer reader yet so I will look through it and try it out and get back to this answer! Thankies!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without knowing what your path will be? Or essentially, where the file will be located?

Comment: Well, assuming its located in the root of your project you just type in the name of your text file + ".txt" under path and you're done.

Comment: Hm, let's say if I turn in the java files to my teacher. Does that mean he has to specifically place the test data files directly with the java files before it would work? I was hoping for a way to find the file even if it wasn't within the project folder

Comment: well a file is defined by it's path. You can have two files with the same name but in the end it's the absolute path that separates those files from each other. This means what you are suggesting is impossible anyway

Comment: Hmm I see, I guess I will ask my teacher during our next session what he wanted the path to be or something. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Gladly. Happy to help